# How to generate multiple files in Thrift?

Tags: thrift

I don't know how to generate more then one thrift files. I tried run `thrift -r --gen java ./*.thrift`. But I fail. So I had to write a shell to build them one by one.

Comment: Can all files be referenced from main ???

Answer (score 5):

Thrift does not accept wildcards. You will have to feed them one by one, or you create a container IDL file which `#includes` them all and then use `-r`.

PS: There is [THRIFT-3013](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3013) but the interest in this seems to have declined a bit.